# A problem on tangents and normals to a curve

Tags: calculus, euclidean-geometry, coordinate-systems

> If a line is tangent to one point and normal at another point on the curve $$x=4t^2 + 3 , y=8t^3 - 1$$, then possible slopes of such a line is?

**what I tried:** 
I got the slope of a tangent at any point on the curve which is $y' $at $t_1 = 3t_1$ and hence slope of normal at the other point ,$y'$ at$ t_2= {1\over-3t_2}$.
After this I formed equations of tangent and normal and compared these to get a relation between $t_1$ and $t_2$. But I seem to get nowhere. Is there any better approach to this. Please help.

Comment: @DavidQuinn I corrected that error. Can you please suggest a solution now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already presumably found the equation of the tangent at the point with parameter value $t$, which is $$y-8t^3+1=3t(x-4t^2-3)$$

Let this line intersect with the curve at a point with parameter value $s$ where $s\neq t$, in which case $s$ satisfies the equation $$(8s^3-1)-8t^3+1=3t((4s^2+3)-4t^2-3)$$

This can be simplified and the resulting cubic in $s$ must have a factor $(s-t)^2$ corresponding to the tangent point. This factor can be removed and we end up with $s=-\frac 12 t$ as the only other solution.

For this tangent to be the same as the normal at point $s$, we require the gradient to be $$-\frac{1}{3s}=3t$$

Solving these two equations for $t$ we end up with $$t=\pm\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}$$

So the possible gradients of the tangents satisfying these conditions are $$m=\pm\sqrt{2}$$

Comment: Though your solution and answer is correct but during solving the cubic equation I got the factor as $(s-t)$ and not as $(s-t)^2$.

Comment: You get $2(s^3-t^3)=3t(s^2-t^2)\implies 2s^3-3s^2t+t^3=0\implies (s-t)^2(2s+t)=0$